# Scala: Array of Maps

Tags: scala

I have an array of maps. In these maps, there is one key whose value is a map itself.  It looks like this.

```
ArrayOfMaps = [{K1: V1, K2: V2, K3: { k1: v1, k2: v2} }, {K1': V1', K2': V2', K3': {k1': v1', k2': v2'}} ... ]
```

I want to have an if condition for k1 (and k1' and k1'' and so on), and if the map passes that condition I want to store that map in another list. I know it's pretty easy, I am not from a scala background. What would be the most efficient way to do this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let me ask you a question: what is the type of your `ArrayOfMaps` variable?  If you were to annotate the type explicitly, what would you declare it as?

Even though Scala has type inference, it is still a statically typed language.  Your variable will have a (static) type, and this will determine what methods are available on it.  And this is a problem here, because the value type of *some* keys in the map is a `V`, and the value type of *other* keys in the map is a `Map[K, V]`.  (In fact, it's a `Map[K, <whatever the overall type is>]` due to the recursive nesting.)

So I would suggest designing what's effectively a union type to represent these two possibilities, for example:

```
trait MapRhs[K, V]
case class JustValue[K, V](v: V) extends MapRhs[K, V]
case class NestedMap[K, V](m: Map[K, MapRhs[K, V]]) extends MapRhs[K, V]
```

Now you can state that your `ArrayOfMaps` is a `Map[K, MapRhs[K, V]]`, and the value type has a more specific type than just `Object`.

When it comes to processing the values however, you almost certainly can't write a single piece of code that runs just as well on a `V` as it does on a nested map.  So the most pragmatic way to handle this would be to pattern match:

```
ArrayOfMaps mapValues {
    case JustValue(x) => // do something with the V1
    case NestedMap(m) => // handle the map
}
```

If your condition is static (or can be parameterised), then instead of pattern matching you could declare it on your trait.  E.g. something like (without knowing any specifics):

```
trait MapRhs[K, V] {
   def meetsYourCondition: Boolean
}
case class JustValue[K, V](v: V) extends MapRhs[K, V] {
   def meetsYourCondition = // some implementation for a V1
}
case class NestedMap[K, V](m: Map[K, MapRhs[V]]) extends MapRhs[K, V] {
   def meetsYourCondition = // some implementation for a nested map
}

// Now the transformation can be
ArrayOfMaps mapValues (_.meetsYourCondition)
```

And if you *can* reduce each element of the map into a boolean true-or-false, then you can turn this into an overall answer by using [`forall`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.AbstractIterable@forall(p:A=>Boolean):Boolean) or [`exists`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.AbstractIterable@exists(p:A=>Boolean):Boolean) instead of `map` (equivalent to joining with `&&` and `||` respectrively).